# How could I implement it next to the existing form so that I can also send an image to the backend? Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm still a beginner in nuxt js, I tried to attach the image to my data stream in several ways, but either the frontend doesn't send anything or I can't read it on the backend. Here is the current code that I would like to extend. I am aware that the header Content-Type:application/json is not suitable for what I want and I have to use multipart/form-data.

```
<template>
    <div class="max-w-md mx-auto mt-8">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Add Recipe</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="space-y-4">

            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="image" class="mb-2 font-bold">Picture:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" ref="image" @change="onFileChange">
            </div>


            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="name" class="mb-2 font-bold">Recipe name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" v-model="recipe.name" class="bg-gray-200 px-4 py-2 border rounded-md" required>
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="description" class="mb-2 font-bold">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="description" v-model="recipe.description" class="bg-gray-200 px-4 py-2 border rounded-md"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-between">
                <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-green-500 rounded-md hover:bg-green-600">Save
                    recipe</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        <p class="flex justify-center text-red-500 mt-4" v-if="errorsMessage" v-html="errorsMessage"></p>
        <p class="flex justify-center text-green-500 mt-4" v-if="succesMessage" v-html="succesMessage"></p>

    </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    const recipe = ref({
        name: '',
        description: ''
    })

    const imageFile = ref(null)

        function onFileChange(event) {
            imageFile.value = event.target.files[0]
    }

    const errorsMessage = ref('')
    const succesMessage = ref('')

    const submit = async () => {

        errorsMessage.value = ''
        succesMessage.value = ''

        try {

            const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: recipe.value.name,
                    description: recipe.value.description
                })
            })

            const data = await response.json()

            if (!response.ok) {

                let backendMessage = JSON.stringify(data.errors)

                backendMessage = JSON.parse(backendMessage)

                for (const key in backendMessage) {
                    backendMessage[key].forEach(errorMsg => {
                        errorsMessage.value += errorMsg + '<br>'
                    })
                }
            } else {
                
                succesMessage.value += data.message
            }

        } catch(error) {}
    }
</script>
```

I tried two different methods.

1.,
I added a new data to the existing row

`formData.append('file', imageFile.value)`

and I changed the headers

'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

This resulted in no data being sent

2.,
I created a formData, added the variables and tried to send it, unfortunately no data was received here either.

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', imageFile.value)
formData.append('name', recipe.value.name)
formData.append('description', recipe.value.description)

const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
})
```

In the second step, if the header 'Content-Type': 'application/json' remains, it sent data, but it is unreadable for the backend or I just don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another place, but the point is that the code should not be restricted. I was close to the solution.
'Content-Type': should not be defined in this case.

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', imageFile.value)
formData.append('name', recipe.value.name)
formData.append('description', recipe.value.description)

const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

That's the solution, I hope it helps others.